# I have an issue with radio button in laravel / HTML

Tags: php, html, laravel

I need my radio button checked in laravel. But i don't know how to fix it.

```
{!! Form::radio('self_paid','no',null, ['class' => 'company_paid'])   !!}
```

I need this radio button to be checked by default.

Comment: `{!! Form::radio('self_paid','no',null, ['class' => 'company_paid','checked'=>'checked'])   !!}` .try this

Comment: radio('self_paid','no',null, true, ['class' => 'company_paid'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `null`, you should use `true`. It accepts boolean value.

```
{!! Form::radio('self_paid','no',true, ['class' => 'company_paid'])   !!}
```

Check this [Radio Button](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#checkboxes-and-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to by default checked then :

```
{!! Form::radio('self_paid','no',true, ['class' => 'company_paid'])   !!}
```

If you want to radio button checked unchecked based on the value of a variable

In controller:

```
    public function index(){
        // variable value for checked radio button (true or 1)         
        $radio_checked = 1; 

        return view('your-blade-view', compact('radio_checked'));
    }
```

In blade file:

```
 {!! Form::radio('self_paid','no',$radio_checked, ['class' => 'company_paid'])   !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Syntax:

```
Form::radio('name', 'value', true);
```

use:

```
{!! Form::radio('self_paid','no',true, ['class' => 'company_paid'])   !!}
```